# Thread-safe operator<<

Tags: c++, thread-safety, mutex

I want to make `operator<<` thread-safe, so it can be used like this

```
log << string << number << object;
```

The problem I'm facing is that `operator<<` is called on each passed argument, so I cannot lock `operator<<` like this because on exit another thread takes the mutex.

```
void logger::info(std::string_view message)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(my_mutex);
    log_message(message);
}
```

Neither I can left this method locked because the deadlock.

Comment: You don't. Implement a template method that accepts any number of arguments and prints them all together.

Comment: You seem to imply that it can *not* be used like `log << string << number << object;` as it is. But I am pretty sure it can. Please elaborate what obstalce you see. Unless of course, you mean that you want it to deduce a critical section from the difference to `log << string << object; log number << object;`.

Comment: What is `log`? Please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

You can make the operator `<<` return an instance of "locked-logger" class that also supports the operator `<<` and will get destroyed (and release lock) at the end of the line. But this isn't advisable as other programmers might find it odd.

It is preferable to write a template method that accepts any number of arguments. Furthermore, streaming isn't a good abstraction for formatting - you'd better check out `fmt` library (its main method `format` is incorporated into C++20). You should base your logger around `fmt` instead of streamers.